# HDR Background not showing on my scene also my cube not reflecting in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>

<script
  async
  src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"
></script>

<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from 'three'
  import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js'
  import { RGBELoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/RGBELoader.js';

  const scene = new THREE.Scene()
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  )
  
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
  const skyboxTexture = new URL('./textures/skybox.hdr', import.meta.url)
 const loader = new RGBELoader()
loader.load(skyboxTexture, function ( texture ) {

                        texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;

                        scene.background = texture;
                        scene.environment = texture;

                    } );
            const   cubeRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget( 256 );
                cubeRenderTarget.texture.type = THREE.HalfFloatType;
  

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
  const cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 1, 1000, cubeRenderTarget );

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, roughness: 0, metalness: 1, envMap: cubeRenderTarget.texture})
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  cube.castShadow = true
  scene.add(cube)

  const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 10)
  light.castShadow = true
//  scene.add(light)
   light.position.z = 2
   light.position.y = 3
  camera.position.z = 5

  
  const gg = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 0.5, 10)
  const gm = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff })
  const ground = new THREE.Mesh(gg, gm)
  ground.receiveShadow = true
  ground.position.y = -3
  scene.add(ground)
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01
    cubeCamera.update( renderer, scene );
  }
  animate()
</script>
```

[image: Files]

My scene doesn't show my HDR background. I also made my cube roughness to 0 and metallic to 1. It's is dark but sometimes show blue color of the ground. Everything is dark. I want to show my HDR background. No errors saying!

I used everything from a YouTube video but not working. Everything is error.

[The tutorial I used](https://youtu.be/6XvqaokjuYU)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the HDR environment map to `Scene.environment` but at the same time your assign the render target of an instance of `CubeCamera` to the materials `envMap` property.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/scenes/Scene.environment) of `Scene.environment`, environment maps assigned to the `envMap` material property have a higher priority. So I suggest you remove the cube camera for now and check again.